# How to generate a CSV from a method that has parameters in ASP.NET MVC using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am able to generate a list of users with their last logons from my AD environment and display it to the view.  However, if I want to export it to a CSV, using the CsvHelper package, I am getting "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'txt_filterDays' of 'HomeController.GetLastLogon(int)'.

If I comment out the method "DownloadCSV()", it works as expected and I can use my input field from the view to change the days.

**View Excerpt**

```
    <form action="GetMostRecentLastLogons" method="post" class="form-inline ml-3">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="text" name="txt_filterDays" placeholder="Days for Last Login">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller Excerpt**

```
    public ActionResult GetMostRecentLastLogons(int txt_filterDays = 90)
    {
        List<LastLogons> MostRecentLastLogons = GetLastLogon(txt_filterDays);
        return View(MostRecentLastLogons);
    }


    public static List<LastLogons> GetLastLogon(int txt_filterDays)
    {
        ...

        MostRecentLogonList = MostRecentLogonList
           .Where(x => x.lastLogon >= CurrentDate.AddDays(-txt_filterDays))
           .GroupBy(x => x.SAMAccountName)
           .Select(scope => scope.OrderBy(x => x.lastLogonServer).Last()).ToList();
    }


    public FileStreamResult DownloadCSV()
    {

        var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon());
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(result);
        return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = "report.csv" };
    }


    public byte[] WriteCsvToMemory(List<LastLogons> MostRecentLogonList)
    {

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        {
            csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LastLogonsMap>();
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(MostRecentLogonList);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The "GetLastLogon()" in the line below is where the error is complaining.  I'm assuming that is happening because I do not have the "txt_filterDays" parameter in the "GetLastLogon()" method?

```
var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon());
```

If I try to add the "txt_filterDays" to:

```
var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon(txt_filterDays));
```

Then it errors out with: The name 'txt_filterDays' does not exist in the current context'

The "DownloadCSV()" works, only if I take out the parameter "int txt_filterDays = 90" on "public ActionResult GetMostRecentLastLogons(int txt_filterDays = 90)", then it dumps to a CSV with no issues, but of course, leaving the ability of changing the days useless.

I've looked for this error and found it numerous times here on StackOverflow but the solutions were for different logic than mine, which, is very confusing to me.

Please let me know how to get this working to accept the "txt_filterDays" parameter inside the "var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon());" line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The definition of your function is:

```
 public static List<LastLogons> GetLastLogon(int txt_filterDays)
```

So in order to call it, you need to pass an integer value just like your definition:

```
//123 here is just an example, apply any integer value on your argument here:
GetLastLogon(123);
```

And not like this on your code above:

```
//What is the integer value that you pass here on GetLastLogon?
var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon());
```

So call `GetLastLogon` with `integer` as an `argument` as I specified on my first line of code above.

Comment: Thank you Willy, I appreciate the response.  While doing so using GetLastLogon(1) for example in var result = WriteCsvToMemory(GetLastLogon(1)); works.  However, I need it to be what ever value I enter in the input field textbox in the view to be and dumped from the WriteCsvToMemory function.

Comment: Ah wait, I think I see what you're saying, let me try that.  Thanks